# How can I make a virtual router on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: networking, router

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and would like to make a virtual router for my Android Device which only connects to infrastructure networks and not ad hoc networks.

I would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd
```

Then, open a text editor program, for example gedit. Copy the following into it.

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid= 
channel=1
hw_mode=g
auth_algs=1
wpa=3 
wpa_passphrase=
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Don't forget to fill in the name of your network after `ssid=` as well as the password after `wpa_passphrase=`.

After all these, save the file as `hostapd.conf` in your home folder.

Now, in your terminal:

```
sudo hostapd hostapd.conf
```

Turn the Wi-Fi connection on in your devices and enjoy the fast network share!

you might also want to add dhcpd to assign address to your Android device. Alternatively you can configure iptables to use NAT

Comment: My computer access internet through authentication server at a uni, where do I place the username and password?