# hostapd error "nl80211: Could not configure driver mode"

Tags: wireless, hostapd

[I would like to make a Virtual Router on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126545/i-would-like-to-make-a-virtual-router-on-ubuntu-12-04)

but i am getting this error message when i run the last terminal command

```
Configuration file: hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

Comment: Are you using 14.04? There is an open bug for hostapd with these error message. [Launchpad bug #1289047 
hostapd package is broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1289047)

Answer (score 33):

As @bain has rightly pointed out, there is a bug raised in launchpad for this very purpose. This workaround suggested there works perfectly for me:

```
sudo nmcli nm wifi off
sudo rfkill unblock wlan

sudo ifconfig wlan0 10.15.0.1/24 up
sleep 1
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
sudo service hostapd restart
```

The first two lines stop wlan from network manager, and then unblocks the interface, so ifconfig can work.

---

**UPDATE:** But if for the first command you get the error message `Error: Object 'nm' is unknown` then use this instead:

```
sudo nmcli radio wifi off
```

---

The next commands uses ifconfig to bring up wlan and allows a second's delay, 
then restart the dhcp server (though I did not need this restart in my setup), and finally
start the hostapd service.

It should now start w/o any issues.

Comment: Newer `nmcli` requires this syntax `sudo nmcli radio wifi off` :)

Comment: This did not change anything

Answer (score 9):

I just had this error on Raspberry pi running Kali linux and hostapd 2.4
I suspected it is because some other network processes are keeping the interface busy, so I ran this airmon-ng command that checks and kills and processes that might use the wifi card:

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

To just see any network processes without killing them, use `airmon-ng check`.
After I killed them, I started hostapd again and no errors came up anymore.

For some other network functionality you might need those processes, I restarted the raspberry for that, but they can also be started individually.

Answer (score 4):

Just mention that according to the bug linked by @bain, the easiest solution is to disable Network Manager for the interface that is to be run with hostapd.

As mentioned there:

```
WORKAROUND: For this to persist through reboots, execute the following in a terminal:
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Add the following entry where the x's are replaced with your WiFi MAC address, save, and then reboot:
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Comment: First thing that works! Network manager was not letting me use my Intel 8260 with hostapd.

Comment: and how i can know if NetworkManager its using it?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.
The first thing I tried was to manually update hostapd from a debian repository from v2.1 to v2.3 . The issue persisted.

I created this script, which is a list of commands that unblock the WLAN driver, and now I finally have a working AP, already deployed in a remote location.

I saved the script to `/usr/bin/enableAP.sh`. Make sure to include it into your crontab so that it is executed at boot.

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/sleep 30
/usr/sbin/service hostapd stop
/usr/sbin/service network-manager stop
/sbin/ifdown wlan0
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 mode Managed
/usr/sbin/rfkill unblock wlan
/usr/bin/nmcli radio wifi off
/usr/sbin/service hostapd stop
/bin/sleep 10
/usr/sbin/service hostapd start
```

if you want to avoid this issue just after installing your new virtual machine and hostapd, you need to block ubuntu from upgrading hostapd:
when you use `sudo apt-get upgrade` it upgrades this package to v2.1, which doesn't work (surely bugged).

You must use `sudo apt-mark hold hostapd` to block future upgrades to Hostapd.

Comment: This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Click the network icon
2. Select "Create wireless network"
3. Choose a name, encryption type and password
4. Click create
5. Make sure you're connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was stopping (which is handled indeed by `airmon-ng check kill`, but that is not necessarily avaialable on the system)  `wpa_supplicant`, otherwise kept getting "Could not configure driver mode"

```
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service
```

or via

```
pkill wpa_supplicant
```