# isc-dhcp-server stops working after ubuntu-desktop is installed

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I am using my Ubuntu Server 16.10 as a hotspot and I install the desktop to use an application but doing this makes isc-dhcp-server stop working. This is the response when I get the status from it:

```
Nov 23 13:49:26 user sh[2394]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Nov 23 13:49:26 user sh[2394]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Nov 23 13:49:26 user sh[2394]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Nov 23 13:49:26 user sh[2394]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Nov 23 13:49:26 user sh[2394]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Nov 23 13:49:26 user sh[2394]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Nov 23 13:49:26 user sh[2394]: exiting.
Nov 23 13:49:26 user systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status
Nov 23 13:49:26 user systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 23 13:49:26 user systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I know it says that it is not configured to listen to the interface but in dhcpd.conf it is.

```
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
INTERFACES="wlp2s0";
subnet 10.255.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
        option routers                  10.255.0.1;
        option subnet-mask              255.255.0.0;
        option broadcast-address        10.255.255.255;
        option domain-name-servers      10.255.0.1;
        range                           10.255.0.25 10.255.255.240;
        default-lease-time              150;
        max-lease-time                  1800;
}
```

The wireless interfaces is wlp2s0 and it still says that it is not configured to listen to the interface. I also included it in /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

```
# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#       Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="wlp2s0"
```

Can somebody please tell me why installing ubuntu-desktop would cause this and how I can fix it. Thanks

Edit:

I ran this:

```
sudo dhcpd -4 wlp2s0
```

And in the information that came up it says:

```
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
PID file: /var/run/dhcpd.pid
Can't open /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases for append.
```

If that is the reason why it isn't working how would I fix it?

I also found out that wlp2s0 isn't being assigned an IP even though network interfaces is correct

```
auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
address 10.255.0.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
```

Comment: I suspect that installing desktop also installed Network Manager and that it is interfering. Check: `sudo service network-manager status`

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem with my Mint 18.3 (Ubuntu 16.04). These are two things that helped to solve it in my case:

1. Remove all empty lines and spaces at the end of the files /etc/network/interface , /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf and /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
2. Add manually the ip to your wireless interface:
   ifconfig wlp2s0:0 10.255.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 up

Check with ifconfig that the ip has been correctly added to your device. Then restart network manager and isc-dhcp-server and see that everything works. Reboot and check that the ip of the device is still set.

Note: if you are using hostapd after all that and you get an error like:

```
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
wlp2s0 (o el que sea): interface state UNITIALIZED - DISABLED
wlp2s0: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlp2s0 wasn't started
```

You have to edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Add the following entry where the x's are replaced with your WiFi MAC address, save, and then reboot:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Sources:
[Set static IP Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/set-static-ip-ubuntu-16-04)

[hostapd error "nl80211: Could not configure driver mode"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472794/hostapd-error-nl80211-could-not-configure-driver-mode)

https://www.garron.me/en/linux/add-secondary-ip-linux.html